# Помогите сделать поле для ввода в sublime 3

Tags: html

я не могу для сайта сделать поле ввода , помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Это поле должно быть в html? Или же это ввод чего-то в sublime? Уточните, что вы имеете в виду, если это html, то приложите какой-нибудь код, картинку того, что вы хотите.

Comment: @SergeyGlazirin, мне кажется он не знает как в sublime консоль открыть

Comment: ну если пишет что для сайта, то явно html) 
В таких случаях лучше хорошо почитать 
[input](http://htmlbook.ru/html/input)

Answer (score 2):

Если ваш вопрос связан с html, то

```
<input type="text" />
```